# Checking a checkbox after pageload

Tags: jquery, asp.net, checkbox

I have a checkbox in my page

If that check box is checked then I want to display a div.
If it is unchecked then another div.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="CBforGrid" />Add CheckBoxes<br />
```

Comment: i agree. i dont spend my time on questions from people with low acceptance.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown the markup for your divs, but assuming they are both hidden to begin with you can do something like this for a one-off on page-load (as implied by your question's title):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   if ($("#CBforGrid").is(":checked"))
      $("#adiv").show();
   else
      $("#anotherdiv").show();
});
```

Or if you mean to do it every time the checkbox is changed by the user then perhaps something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $aDiv = $("#adiv").hide(),
        $anotherDiv = $("#anotherDiv");

    $("#CBforGrid").click(function() {
       $aDiv[this.checked ? "show" : "hide"]();
       $anotherDiv[this.checked ? "hide" : "show"]();
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Vk6R8/

Answer (score -1):

on Page Load

```
$(function(){
   if($('#CBforGrid').is(':checked')) {
        $('div').show();
   }
});
```

On CheckBox Click

```
   $(function(){
      $('#CBforGrid').click(function(){

          if($(this).is(':checked')) {
               $('div').show();
           } else {
               $('div').hide();
           }

      });

    });
```